HTMLInputElement maxLength property has an invalid default value
We're developing a web component library. We're using ShadowDOM and inside that, native HTMLInputElement instances. Since we're aiming to widely be compatible with native inputs, we're mirroring the native API to the internal HTMLInputElement.
For this to work properly in Storybook, every supported property needs to have a default value, which, for HTMLInputElement's maxLength (same for minLength) property happens to be a seemingly invalid value: -1.
Trying to assign this default value to the property results in a DOMException:


let input = document.createElement('input')
console.log(input.maxLength);

input.maxLength = input.maxLength;
// Throws 
// DOMException, Uncaught IndexSizeError: 
// Failed to set the 'maxLength' property on 'HTMLInputElement':
// The value provided (-1) is not positive or 0.



How can I meaningfully provide a non-damaging default value for the property that doesn't throw when set?

"Since we want to be compatible with native inputs, we're mirroring the native API to the internal HTMLInputElement"... there are IIRC ~21 different flavors of input. You sure you want to do that? I find it funny because that's usually one of my go-to examples of why I refuse to use web components as the basis of a component library. As for your actual question, why can't you just insert a conditional check to use zero as the default value if it's set to -1? I'm guessing it wouldn't be the first time you had to work around a wonky web API...

If you set input.maxLength = 0 then the user can no longer type in the input. That's why I added the term "non-damaging" to my question...

This conundrum begs the question of whether every well-crafted form input should have an explicit and appropriate maxlength. It's hard for me to answer "no". However, any non-zero value is a wild uninformed guess for any given input. Thus perhaps for people who don't make well-crafted forms, some random large number (1000? 4096?) would be as good a guess as any.

In the provided example the value of input.maxLengthis undefined. And undefined values are not allowed to assign.

@Reporter Firefox reports -1.

@Reporter Firefox, Chrome and Safari each report -1. What browser are you seeing undefined in?

I used Intenet exploer, Sorry my fault.

I'm not sure to understand why you need to set this default value, could you clarify please? As I understand it, you have a custom element that acts as a wrapper, right? Can't you just make that element's getter return the input's value and its setter set it? Or is the issue that Storybook (which I'm not familiar with btw), does set a default value that's not valid? In that case can't you just wrap the input's setter in a try catch inside your element's setter?

Ps: In case that's what you're after, to set it back to -1 after setting the maxLength IDL, you'd need to remove the content attribute (removeAttribute("maxlength")) From the IDL I don't think there is a way to set it back to unset.

input.maxLength = undefined ? Doesn't get you exact behavior, but at least does not throw an error

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman That's coerced to 0
